# Find class of closest <i> element

Tags: jquery

In the following markup, I want to find the class of the closest `i`. I am trying following jQuery but it does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="item1" class="item">
    <div class="text"><i class="class1"></i></div>
    <div class="edit">Change</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
      var closest = $(this).closest('i').attr('class');
     alert(closest);    
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BRnes/

Comment: closest will only select the same node and parent nodes. you need `siblings().children('i')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`closest()` will only select the same node and parent nodes. you need `siblings().children('i')`

http://jsfiddle.net/BRnes/3/

See the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) for more information about tree traversal.

Answer (score 2):

```
var closest = $(this).prev().children('i').attr('class');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BRnes/5/)

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` finds the closest parent since that doesn't appear to be what you are after you may consider `.siblings.find('i')` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
      var closest = $(this).prev('.text').find('i').attr('class');
     alert(closest);    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/uEsWk/)**

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/BRnes/2/

```
$('.edit').click(function(){ 
      var closest = $('.text').find('i').attr('class');
     alert(closest);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`closest` will only find parent elements. If the `i` is always going to be under the `.text` element, you could do:

```
$(this).prev(".text").find("i");
```

This will find the previous `.text` element, then any `i` elements underneath it.